# When (and when not) to use the new keyword in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I have two contracts in Solidity like so (based upon a tutorial):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract ERC20Token {
    string public name;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    
    function mint() public {
        balances[tx.origin]++;
    }
}

contract MyContract {
    address payable wallet;
    address public token;
    
    constructor(address payable _wallet, address _token)  {
        wallet = _wallet;
        token = _token;
    }
    function buyToken() public payable {
        ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token));
        _token.mint();
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

My question is why they use **ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token));** in order to access the class and call he .mint() function.

My base reflex would be to do the following instead:

```
ERC20Token _token = new ERC20Token();
_token.mint();
```

This is because the ERC20Token contract does not have a constructor, so I'm unsure where the `RC20Token(address(token))` constructor parameters come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new ERC20Token()` expression deploys a new `ERC20Token` contract and returns its (newly deployed) address.

Since your `ERC20Token` doesn't have any constructor (and constructor params), you don't need to pass any params. But if it did have constructor params, you'd need to pass them. Example:

```
contract ERC20Token {
    constructor (string memory _name, string memory _symbol) {
    }
}
```

```
address deployedTo = new ERC20Token("MyToken", "MyT");
```

---

The `ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(<address>)` creates a helper object allowing the `_token` to be treated as a contract implementing the `ERC20Token` interface, so you can execute and call its `public` and `external` functions.

It's the address of the external contract that you're passing - not the constructor params.

```
contract ERC20Token {
    function mint() public {
    }
}
```

```
ERC20Token _token = ERC20Token(address(token));
_token.mint();
```